# Liquidbase Migrations in a clustered environment?

Tags: liquibase, dropwizard

For background, we utilize dropwizard and liquibase for a project. This project deploys in multiple instances when going to production.

We've run into rare instances where a new database insert script will run in more than one instance during deployment (creating duplicate data). Normally, this isn't a huge problem because 1.) We don't typically insert data as part of an upgrade script, and 2.) Most of our tables are designed in such a way that it would prevent a double insert anyway.

But it raised an interesting question, especially since I've been playing around in quartz for clustered job scheduling. Is there something similar we can do for liquibase, where we can prevent the same upgrade script from running simultaneously on different instances that touch the same database? Or is this something built-in to liquibase and we have just run into weird edge cases?

I can't find any documentation for such a scenario, which makes me think that we have just run across something strange (or that we should fix some of our old legacy tables and stop thinking about it.)

Apologize for leaving things a bit vague but this is more of a thought experiment than a request on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what clustered environment mean exactly (are you running in kubernetes, some custom cluster, ...).

Anyway, there is a `databasechangeloglock` table which should be something like "distributed lock". So if one instance creates lock another one shouldn't be able to create it. But if you look into [Liquibase repo](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+lock)  you will probably find some issues regarding this.

If you are running in Kubernetes, then you can create a [init or side container](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/using-liquibase-in-kubernetes) which executes the changes on new deployment before the first pod even starts.

**EDIT:**

just make sure table `databasechangeloglock` has the same name and schema, it's possible to change it.